# Python give full permissions to read/write a file

Tags: python, linux, file, pid

While working on Python(3.8.0), I am trying to create a PID file in the /var/run directory. On **enter**, I need to create the file and on **exit**, I need to delete the file.

```
class PIDFile(object):
    def __init__(self, filename='pidfileCreated.pid'):
        self._file = os.path.join("/var/run", filename)

    def __enter__(self):

        with open(self._file, "w") as f:
            f.write(str(os.getpid()))
            f.close()
            os.chmod(self._file, 0o777)

        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        if os.path.exists(self._file):
            try:
                os.remove(self._file)
            except OSError:
                pass
```

But I get the error -

```
with open(self._file, "w") as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/run/pidfileCreated.pid'
```

Comment: In general, only root can create/delete files in /var/run. Are you asking for a way to circumvent that? Why?

Comment: I need to create/access/delete PID file for my service, which gets executed by this Python script. The suggested location for storing the PID files is "/var/run" folder. Please suggest if otherwise.

Comment: Can you settle for a subfolder of /var/run instead of directly in it?

Comment: I think having a subfolder won't be a problem. But when I use "/var/run/tmp" in the code above, then I get the error "No such file or directory: '/var/run/tmp/pidfileCreated.pid'"

Comment: That's because you need to make `/var/run/tmp` as root first.

Comment: How exactly are you suggesting (code wise)?

Comment: Your code can't do that, since it's not root. You need to manually do that as root.

Comment: The python script needs to be executed on other machines too. I can do it on my local, but not on other machines. I need to find a way to handle this situation through code only.

Comment: Then you need to put the PID file somewhere else.

Comment: Not sure if there is any suggested location apart from /var/run/ to place the PID files. Followed - https://superuser.com/questions/454449/linux-alternative-places-where-to-store-pid-file-instead-of-var-run but even that mentions "/var/run/"

Comment: There's both [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/454449/linux-alternative-places-where-to-store-pid-file-instead-of-var-run#comment530582_454449) and [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/981148/700114) in the very question that you linked, that give you alternatives.

Comment: `/var/run` is mainly used for system daemons, which are run by root, not for programs that are run by ordinary users.

Comment: Why don't you try the second answer https://superuser.com/a/981148/866386 in your reference link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the Python executable using command line? If you are not, please try to run with command line using root privilege. And I don't think it's possible to create `/var/run` without the usage of root privileges as it would create security issues. For instance, one could replace an existing folder/file with a folder/file that has the same name with forced replace parameter.